# javascript - automatically click on netflix interactive movie choices

Tags: javascript, firefox, click, firefox-addon

I am looking for a method that can automatically click on the interactive choices in some Netflix movies.

I've tried a lot of things, but it seems that only the focus event works:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("BranchingInteractiveScene--choice-selection")[0]
        .dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
```

Using `.click()`, `.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'))` and many similar methods on this element does not work for some reason.

Looking at things in the inspector from Firefox, you can see the `click` method is missing. But a normal click with the mouse on that element works just fine.

[image]

Anyone got an idea what other methods I could try out, to make this work?

---

**UPDATE 1**: Just found out about this debug function in firefox. Hopefully it tells me how the click event needs to look like.

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**: With this debug tool I now managed to trigger click events almost identical to the ones a normal mouse click creates. The only two non-identical properties left are `isTrusted` (is `false` instead of `true`) and `mozInputSource` (is `0` instead of `1`). Here is the code I got so far:

```js
const wrapperClassName = "ResizingAspect--wrapper";
const containerClassName = "ResizingAspect--container";
const choicesClassName = "BranchingInteractiveScene--choice-selection";

function clickChoice(choiceNr) {
  document.activeElement.blur();
  const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName(wrapperClassName)[0];
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName(containerClassName)[0];
  const button = document.getElementsByClassName(choicesClassName)[choiceNr];
  if (!button) throw new Error("Unable to find element");
  const bounding = button.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = bounding.left + bounding.width / 2;
  const y = bounding.top + bounding.height / 2;
  var event = new MouseEvent("click", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y,
    composed: true,
    detail: 1,
    screenX: x + (wrapper.clientWidth - container.clientWidth) / 2,
    screenY: y + (wrapper.clientHeight - container.clientHeight) / 2,
  });
  // FIXME isTrusted != true;
  // FIXME mozInputSource != 1;
  button.firstChild.dispatchEvent(event);
  console.log("clicked (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
}
```

It still does not select the choices automatically though... My guess would be that the problem lies in the `isTrusted = false` part.

---

**UPDATE 3**:
It is not the most beautiful workaround, but as I haven't found any real solution so far what follows is better than giving up. That said, I have now written a java overlay application that uses the `java.awt.Robot` class which works as an autoclicker. That java application is then controlled by http requests from the Firefox add-on sent over `localhost`.

Comment: I would check if the item you are triggering the event on is actually the item that has the event listener attached. I might be bubbling up a couple of levels where the actual event listener lives

Comment: Just checked all the elements with event listeners, and the only one with a `click` event is the `nfp nf-player-container` about nine levels up from where I was looking. No idea why they implemented it up there or how to inject my 'select choice' click event, but I guess I'm one step closer now. thx.