# Does a Netflix video player source code documentation exist?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, netflix

I am [seaching for a function that simulates clicks on a choice of a Netflix interactive movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70118725/javascript-automatically-click-on-netflix-interactive-movie-choices), but it seems to be a little more difficult than I thought.

What would probably help is more readable version of the '[cadmium playercore 6](https://assets.nflxext.com/en_us/ffe/player/html/cadmium-playercore-6.0033.179.911.js)' and the '[akira player](https://codex.nflxext.com/%5E3.0.0/truthBundle/webui/1.22.5-akira-js-vafe38bd5/js/js/akira%7CakiraClient.js/2/0a31032F2P30050k00322O2Y072S2R2M2X2H2Q2-2Z0L/l/true/none)' as all the variable names are replaced by gibberish in these versions. The part that I am most interested in is the part where the click event gets assigned to the `nfp nf-player-container` that is probably used to trigger the interactive choices.

Is there any version out there that is a little bit more readable or maybe even a documentation of the Netflix video player source code?